# How to set equal scale's length in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Hi
Is it possible in gnuplot to set scales so that length of scaleX and scaleY would be the same??
I tried different tricks (set size, set ratio etc) but even if the range of scaleX and scaleY is the same - the length of that scales are different. It looks like length of range from 0 to 1(on scalex) is greater then length of range from 0 to 1 (on scaleY).

Comment: Did you give 'set ratio -1' a try?

Comment: Yes, but it also  didn't work

Comment: @Woltan: I think you meant `set size ratio -1` to have the same aspect ratio

Answer (score 56):

Actually, `set size ratio -1` set the same ratio in all direction independently of the window while `set size square` plot in a square box, no matter what range you use.

Answer (score 29):

Well,
now that we found the answer (see comments of the question), I might just as well post it for others to find it more easily:

```
set size square
```

does the trick.

Cherio Woltan

Answer (score 23):

That works fine for plot (2D). For splot (3D) use
`set view equal xyz`

Comment: No, that is not the same! `set size square` sets the `x` and `y` axis to the same length, whereas `set view equal xyz` uses the same unit length for all axes. Example: `reset; set xrange[-5:5]; set yrange[-1:1]; set view equal xy; set multiplot layout 2,1; plot x; set size square; plot x; unset multiplot`