# GNUplot Autoscale set xrange equal to yrange

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm using GNUplot to plot orbits from a datafile. I want to use `autoscale xy` so that the GNUplot script does not need to edited depending on the data. However, when I plot, `autoscale` doesn't set the `xrange` to be the same as `yrange`. This makes the orbits look "squashed".

I've tried using `set size square` and `set size ratio -1`
[How to set equal scale's length in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239294/how-to-set-equal-scales-length-in-gnuplot).

But this didn't work.

Is there anyway to force `autoscale` to make the x and y ranges equal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no option to autoscale x- and y-range to the same values. Here is a solution, how you can do this with some tricks.

If you want to keep gnuplot's extending of the ranges to the next tics, you can do it as follows:

You must first plot once using the `unknown` terminal. This saves the x- and y-ranges in the gnuplot variables `GPVAL_X_MIN`, `GPVAL_X_MAX`, `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX`. Then you set the ranges and replot:

```
set terminal push # save current terminal
set terminal unknown
plot 'datafile'
set terminal pop # restore previous terminal

min = (GPVAL_Y_MIN < GPVAL_X_MIN ? GPVAL_Y_MIN : GPVAL_X_MIN)
max = (GPVAL_Y_MAX > GPVAL_X_MAX ? GPVAL_Y_MAX : GPVAL_X_MAX)

set xrange[min:max]
set yrange[min:max]
set size ratio -1

replot
```

The push/pop stuff is required only if you want to keep the initial terminal settings.

To make this reusable, e.g. for use with `multiplot`, you can wrap all those commands inside a string and call `eval` on it:

```
autoscale_xy(datafile) = \
    "set terminal push; set terminal unknown; set autoscale;".\
    "plot '".datafile."'; set terminal pop;".\
    "min = (GPVAL_Y_MIN < GPVAL_X_MIN ? GPVAL_Y_MIN : GPVAL_X_MIN);".\
    "max = (GPVAL_Y_MAX > GPVAL_X_MAX ? GPVAL_Y_MAX : GPVAL_X_MAX);".\
    "set xrange[min:max]; set yrange[min:max];"
...

files = "first second third fourth"
do for [f in files] {
    eval(autoscale_xy(f))
    plot f
}
```

Another option would be to use `stats` to compute the maximum and minimum x- and y-values and set the ranges accordingly:

```
stats 'datafile' using 1:2 nooutput
min = (STATS_min_y < STATS_min_x ? STATS_min_y : STATS_min_x)
min = (STATS_max_y > STATS_max_x ? STATS_max_y : STATS_max_x)

sc = 1.05
set xrange[sc*min:sc*max]
set yrange[sc*min:sc*max]
set size ratio -1

plot 'datafile'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This method is rather frustrating, however, as I am using `multiplot` to plot 4 graphs from different columns in the data file. having to do this for each data set is not ideal, but workable.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I updated my answer to show you how you can put all this stuff in a string and use `eval` to make it reusable.